# Как добавить в ExpandableListView к ParentGroup ImageButton?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Для решаемой задачи необходимо выполнять сверку записей, подгруженных с сервера с `SQLite` базой самого устройства и добавлять/удалять при отсутствии/наличии (добавление в избранное). Уже сделал метод для заполнения `ExpandableListView`, но не знаю как в родительскую группу добавить `ImageButton`.
Ниже код самого метода

```
public void setExpandableListView(ArrayList<Dish> val){
    Map<String, String> map;
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> groupDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Dish> values = val;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("dishName", values.get(i).getName());
        groupDataList.add(map);
    }
    String groupFrom[] = new String[] { "dishName" };
    int groupTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, String>>> сhildDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> сhildDataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("dishRecipe", values.get(i).getRecipe());
        сhildDataItemList.add(map);
        сhildDataList.add(сhildDataItemList);
    }

    String childFrom[] = new String[] { "dishRecipe" };
    int childTo[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

    final SimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupDataList,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, groupFrom,
            groupTo, сhildDataList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            childFrom, childTo);

    final ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_recipes);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
    list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == currentNumOfDishes){
                String[] query = new String[2];
                query[1] = "get_dishes";
                query[0] = "SELECT * FROM Dishes WHERE _id > " + currentNumOfDishes + " AND _id <= " + neededNumOfDishes;
                new AsyncRequest(Recipes_List.this).execute(query);
                scroll = currentNumOfDishes;
                scrollcount = visibleItemCount;
                currentNumOfDishes = neededNumOfDishes;
                neededNumOfDishes += 20;
            }
        }
    });
    if (scroll > 1){
        list.setSelectedGroup(scroll-scrollcount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве layout для групп сейчас у Вас используется ресурс предоставляемый Андроид: android.R.id.text1 . Вам нужно создать свой ресурс layout для групп, с необходимой разметкой (добавление ImageButton и т.п.), ну и в коде уже соответственно ссылаться на него. Ну и скорее всего тоже самое следует сделать и для элементов child.

Comment: А в разметку помещать ImageButton и TextView, я так понимаю?

Comment: да, разметку Вы создаете ту, которая Вам нужна. Если нужны ImageButton и TextView то размещаете в ней их.

Comment: спасибо большое, как сделаю отмечу )

Comment: уже даже неловко тревожить, но проблема не решилась, ибо никакой реакции на замену ресурса для групп не удается получить (ни положительной, ни отрицательной)

Замену делал так:
...
    int groupTo[] = new int[] { R.drawable.fav_adapter };
...

fav_adapter.xml выглядит так:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/group"

Comment: android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</selector>

(Извиняюсь, в комментариях нету нормального форматирования)

Comment: попробуйте разметку для group сделать LinearLayout , в нее поместить ImageButton, а в нем, если нужно, ссылайтесь на selector xmlns атрибутом: android:src = "@drawable/ fav_adapter.xml"